# Add the specific hour to a given date in shell script

Tags: shell, date

In my shell, when a date is given with YYYYmmddHHMM format, I would like to add an hour to the given date.
My current code is as below:

```
DATE=201502252310
NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M -ud "$DATE +1 hour")
echo $NEXT_DATE
```

When the given date is `201502121010`, the result is `2015021210100100`.
In fact, I'd like to get `201502121110`.

When the given date is `201502122310`, the result I'd like to get is `201502130010`.
But, it shows `date: invalid date '201502122310 +1 hour'`.

It seems my code is something wrong.
How can I do to add the specific hour to the given date correctly???

Comment: what time zone are you in?

Comment: @glennjackman The time zone is UTC.

Comment: It looks like date cannot parse your $DATE value: you may have to insert some hyphens and colons

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for your help. It is ok now. I add some hyphens in date and colon in time as  `DATE=2015-02-10` `TIME=23:10`. And I use them as `NEXT_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M -ud "$DATE $TIME UTC +1 hour")`. I got the result `201502110010`.

Comment: It is also OK when I don't add some hyphens and colons. The main point is that I separate the date and time. When they are separately used, the problem can be solved and the hour increases. :)